# veins omnet customized map and osmWebWizard export

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using latest version of veins. I have been playing it with for a while and understand the basics now. I followed tictoc tutorial for omentpp, but I still couldn't figure out how to solve the following probelm:

1. What should I set the playgroundsize so the [background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVOWY.jpg) can match the obstacle block? 
   That is too large now.

   `*.playgroundSizeX = 3932m
   *.playgroundSizeY = 2500m
   *.playgroundSizeZ = 50m`
2. I used the **osmWebWizard.py** to generate the map for my simulation, but why my map doesn't display the obstacle block?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this would work. OMNeT++ 5.6.1 supports setting a background image (see https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:background-displaystring-tags)  and adjusting its size, but not its offset. While you can adjust the offset that is applied to SUMO cars (with respect to their OMNeT++ position) that approach is limited in that it applies a symmetric offset. If you want to match the background image to what's happening on the simulation playground, you would need to manipulate the image itself (using an image editor).

A more workable solution might be to use write a module using the OMNeT++ canvas feature to compose an image onto the background.